# Errors using the Comparator interface

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue, comparator

I am trying to write a simple application with priority queues. I am getting the following errors --" error: leastPriority is not abstract and does not override abstract method compare(Integer,Integer) in Comparator" and "error: incompatible types
Comparator cmp = new leastPriority(); "

Can someone point out the problem with this code.

My code is :

```
class leastPriority implements Comparator<Integer> {    
    public int compare(Reservation x, Reservation y){
        if(x.getPriority() > y.getPriority()){
            return -1;
        }
        if(x.getPriority() < y.getPriority()){
            return +1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public class prioQueue{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Comparator<Reservation> cmp = new leastPriority();
        PriorityQueue<Reservation> queue = new PriorityQueue<Reservation>(10,cmp);
        queue.add(new Reservation(1,"Andy",10));
        queue.add(new Reservation(1,"Peter",1));
        queue.add(new Reservation(1,"John",4));

        while(true){
            Reservation r = queue.poll();
            if(r==null){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(r.getName());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your type parameter for `Comparator<T>` and your `compare(T o1, T o2)` method's parameters does not match. Since in the interface they are the same, you need to give identical types to them.

Change this:

```
class leastPriority implements Comparator<Integer>
```

to:

```
class leastPriority implements Comparator<Reservation>
```

Comment: Thanks .. Stupid mistake :P

Answer (score 1):

`leastPriority` should implement `Comparator<Reservation>` instead of `Comparator<Integer>`. The generic type is the one that's accepted as a parameter in your `compare()` method.

P.S. It's a good practice to name all Java classes with a first uppercase letter (`PrioQueue`) and (`LeastPriority`).